# Is it possible to compile PDFRender to run on JRE 1.4?

Tags: javac, java, java-5, jdk1.4

I would like to use a PDF to image conversion API for Java, [PDF-Renderer](http://java.net/projects/pdf-renderer) seems to be quite good. As it's been written for JRE 1.5 compliance, I get alot of compile errors when I try to compile down to 1.4. I have tried tweeking the compiler compatibility options without success. So, is there a 1.4 compatible build for PDF Renderer ? If not would like to know if there are any other options for a PDF=> image renderer in java that is compatible with JRE 1.4.2+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are running javac use command line option `-target 1.4`. Due to java 1.5 added generics and enum that both are compiler features I believe that javac will succeed to generate 1.4-compatible byte code.

But you will probably have some problems later. For example if PDFERenderer uses java classes from JDK 1.5 that cannot be found in JDK 1.4.... In this case you can try to add them to bootclasspath when you are running your application but I cannot guarantee success because classes may depend on other classes etc...

You can try but I'd personally recommend you to move forward to java 1.6. :)

Comment: Moving to 1.5 is a last resort, but due to the JVM's in the fleet of  systems we're designing for, 1.4 would catch 90+%, but 1.5 it drops to 70%. Wish the client base would move with the times to, 1.4 is almost 10 years old!  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#J2SE_1.4_.28February_6.2C_2002.29 Sigh!